# Partial Möbius convolutions

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, mobius-inversion

I am well aware of the Möbius inversion formula, which states
$$\sum_{d \mid q} \mu(q/d) = \mathbf{1}_{q=1}$$

Do we know how to give a closed formula for the "partial" such convolution
$$\sum_{a \mid d \mid q} \mu(q/d) = \sum_{d \mid q/a} \mu(q/d) = ?$$

Comment: Note that the last sum in this post is precisely an instance of the first sum, with $q$ replaced by $q/a$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $d=at$, so we have

$$
S=\sum_{\substack{t\in\mathbb Z\\at|q}}\mu\left(q\over at\right)=\sum_{t|(q/a)}\mu\left(q/a\over t\right)=\mathbf{1}_{q=a}.
$$